# Iterate through Wagtail Snippets Inline Objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-admin, wagtail

I have a restaurant menu with 2 models.  A `Product` model and a `MenuSelection` model.  A product can belong to many menus.  The `MenuSelection` is added to `Product` as an inline relationship.

The challenge I am having is listing menu objects in `ModelAdmin` `list_display`.  Do I need to create a ForeignKey relationship or create a @property that iterates through the Inline objects?  I definitely hit another wall in my experience.  Any help would be much appreciated.

**MenuSelection**

```
class MenuSelection(ClusterableModel):
    menu_section = models.CharField(default=None, max_length=100, choices=MENU_CHOICES, unique=True, verbose_name='Menu Section')
    menu = models.CharField(default=None, max_length=100, choices=MENU, unique=True, verbose_name='Menu')
    menu_price = models.DecimalField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        max_digits=5,
        decimal_places=2,
        verbose_name='Menu Price',
        help_text='Numbers only with 2 digital decimal. I.e. 25.00'
    )

    panels = [

        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
                FieldPanel('menu'),
                FieldPanel('menu_section'),
                FieldPanel('menu_price'),
            ],
            heading="Menu & Prices",
            classname="collapsible"
        ),
    ]
```

**Product**

```
class ProductMenuPrices(Orderable, MenuSelection):
    page = ParentalKey('Product', related_name='menu_selection')


@register_snippet
class Product(ClusterableModel):
    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Menu Item')
    product_description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Product Description', blank=True)

    panels = [
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
                FieldPanel('product_title'),
                FieldPanel('product_description'),
                InlinePanel('menu_selection', label="Menu & Price Assignment", max_num=3),
            ],
            heading="Product Detail",
            classname="collapsible"
        ),
    ]

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Menu Item'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_title
```

**ProductModelAdmin**

```
class ProductModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = Product
    menu_label = 'Menu'
    menu_icon = 'snippet'
    menu_order = 300
    add_to_settings_menu = False
    exclude_from_explorer = False
    list_display = ('product_title', 'product_description')
    list_filter = 'product_title',
    search_fields = 'product_title',


modeladmin_register(ProductModelAdmin)
```

Comment: Is this about django admin or about wagtail snippets in the wagtail admin?

Comment: Sorry, these are being built with Snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
   class Product(ClusterableModel):

       def get_menu_selection(self):
           menu_selection = self.menu_selection.count()
           return menu_selection

    class ProductModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):

        list_display = ('product_title', 'get_menu_selection')
```

Cheers,

Robert

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to be a relation in the wagtail snippets admin you need to use their approach for it.

Here is an **untested** example based on my code, adopted to your use case:

```
@register_snippet
class MenuSelection(ClusterableModel):
    # fields...

    def product_list(self):
        return ', '.join([menuproduct.product.name for menuproduct in self.products.all()])

    panels = [
        # field panels
        InlinePanel('products', label="Products", min_num=1)
    ]


@register_snippet
class Product(ClusterableModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # fields ...

    @property
    def menu_selections(self):
        MenuSelection.objects.filter(products__in=[self])


class MenuSelectionProduct(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    menu_selection = ParentalKey(MenuSelection, related_name='products')
```

The `MenuSelectionProduct` defines a `ParentalKey` with a `related_name`. This way you tell the django ORM to make this relation available on `MenuSelection`.
This enables you to create a `InlinePanel` on `MenuSelection` for this through model.
The method `product_list` is an example on how to work with this relation further on `MenuSelection` objects. And the property `menu_selection` on `Product` can be used to resolve the relation from the other direction.

Comment: I guess that `Product` must not be a `ClusterableModel`. It was in my code because I had similar relations between my model and others. But I'm not sure at the moment.